# Locate the same area of an ImageView regardless of scaling

Tags: android, graphics, imageview

I want to identify a certain part of an ImageView -- based on the actual size of the image regardless of how the image is scaled for the particular device.

Example: I have an image that is 480x320. I want a rectangle that (at this size) is defined as 
Rect(10,35,20,50).  What I'm wanting to do is figure out how I can define this rectangle relative to the *actual* size of the image when it scaled and displayed on the screen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you just scale each part of the rectangle?  For instance, if your image is displayed at 2x -- 960x480 -- then would the correct rectangle be (20,70,40,100)?

Answer (score 0):

Use percentages from a pivot point: the top-left or the bottom-right.